# Design patterns to override attributes of object and validate them

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, architecture

GOAL:

I want to build a "market validation control engine" that validates players' actions and limits on the market.

SUMMARY:

Consider that we have a `Character` object that can buy only a given number of `Item` objects, e.g `Arrow`. The number depends on `Race`, `Tire` and `Area` where a lower layout of hierarchy overrides the upper; if the limit isn't specified lower layout inherits it from the upper:

[image]

For example:

- *Pro ELF in Forest* can **buy** up to 2000 arrows
- *Basic Ork in Forest* and *Basic Ork in Desert* can **buy** 50 arrows.

Additionally, the `Character` object can `Buy` and `Sell` a specific amount of arrows on the market. The amount and action depend on the `Area`. Otherway to say is every node might have its validation rules.
For example:

- *Basic Elf in Desert* can **sell** 50% arrows
- *Basic Orc in Desert* can **sell** 100% of the arrows.

Lastly, based on the `Tier` players can `Exchange` arrows to another item. For example :

- *Pro ELF* can **exchange** 100% of its arrows

STRUGGLES:

1. Building hierarchy
2. Validation rules. Every layout of hierarchy (`Tier` or `Area`) have rules
3. How to make 1 and 3 work together
4. Scalability. Adding a new layout (e.g. `Clan`) or attaching a new validation rule to `Area`
5. Maintenance

I am almost sure that I need multiple different patterns here. Currently, I'm thinking of the **Decorator Pattern** for creating hierarchy object with all the limits and the **Chain of Responsibility** for the rule validation. However, I am not sure how well these patterns will work together in the long ran.

UPD: In the example, I used `Arrow` - one of the hundreds of items on the market and `Desert` with `Forest` - two of the 9 areas.

Comment: From your diagram, there are 4 levels. At the bottom, a Pro Forest Orc could buy 150 arrows. I understand that. But, 2 levels up, an normal Orc only could buy 50. My question is, does such Orc exist? Could an Orc with no tier and area exists in the game?

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski if the lower layout of the hierarchy (child) doesn't have a limit then it inherits that limit from the upper layout (parent).

Comment: Want to know about the definition of `Area` in your application. Is it a location of the character currently travelling? Or is it the habitat of the character (like arctic wolf and grey wolf)

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski `Area` represents the current location. However, the `Character` could, but almost never wouldn't leave its area.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few different ways to implement this so I'm assuming you're not really sure where to start.

I've written up some example code using classes. In this, there's 2 ways that we could store the item (arrow) data.

**Nested Array** - This allows for a more "structured" approach. It also allows you to easily add more attributes to each "child" array if necessary.

**Serialized Map** - This has a much smaller code footprint and is generally quicker.

**NOTE:** This code is not setup to be well-performing (in reference to speed) but as a way to see how you could setup this system.

There are 3 files here `index.php`, `Character.class.php`, `Market.class.php`.

There are 2 main methods on the `Market` class: `getNestedLimit()` and `getSerializedLimit()`. Each one shows how you would get the limit based on those example structures.

```php
<?php
// index.php

require_once __DIR__ . "/Character.class.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/Market.class.php";

$market = new Market;

$orc_a = new Character("orc", "basic", "desert");
$orc_b = new Character("orc", "pro", "forest");

$market->getNestedLimit($orc_a, "arrow"); // 50
$market->getNestedLimit($orc_b, "arrow"); // 150

$elf_a = new Character("elf", "pro", "forest");
$elf_b = new Character("elf", "pro", "desert");

$market->getSerializedLimit($elf_a, "arrow"); // 2000
$market->getSerializedLimit($elf_b, "arrow"); // 50
```

```php
<?php 
// Character.class.php
class Character {
    public string $race;
    public ?string $tier = null;
    public ?string $area = null;

    public function __construct(
        string $race,
        ?string $tier = null,
        ?string $area = null,
    ) {
        $this->race = $race;
        $this->tier = $tier;
        $this->area = $area;
    }
}
```

```php
// Market.class.php
class Market {
    public $nested_items = [
        "arrow" => [
            "limit" => [
                "_base" => 0,
                "race" => [
                    "orc" => [
                        "_base" => 50,
                        "tier" => [
                            "basic" => [
                                "area" => [],
                            ],
                            "pro" => [
                                "area" => [
                                    "desert" => 50,
                                    "forest" => 150,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    "elf" => [
                        "_base" => 1000,
                        "tier" => [
                            "basic" => [
                                "area" => [
                                    "desert" => 150,
                                    "forest" => 1000,
                                ],
                            ],
                            "pro" => [
                                "area" => [
                                    "desert" => 50,
                                    "forest" => 2000,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    public function getNestedLimit(Character $character, string $item_id) {
        $item  = $this->nested_items[$item_id];
        $item_limit = $item["limit"];

        $actual_limit = $item_limit["_base"];

        // check race
        if (isset($item_limit["race"][$character->race])) {
            $race_limit = $item_limit["race"][$character->race];
            if (isset($race_limit["_base"])) {
                // value exists - use this
                $actual_limit = $race_limit["_base"];
            }

            // check tier
            if (isset($race_limit["tier"][$character->tier])) {
                $tier_limit = $race_limit["tier"][$character->tier];
                if (isset($tier_limit["_base"])) {
                    // value exists - use this
                    $actual_limit = $tier_limit["_base"];
                }

                // check area
                if (isset($tier_limit["area"][$character->area])) {
                    $actual_limit = $tier_limit["area"][$character->area];
                }
            }
        }

        return $actual_limit;
    }

    /** Serialize syntax: 
     * {race}[-{tier}[-{area}]]
     * e.g.
     *     "Pro tier orc in forest" -> "o-p-f"
     *     "Basic tier elf" -> "e-b"
     *     "Orc" -> "o"
     *
     * When determining the limit, pick the most specific first.
     */
    public $serialized_items = [
        "arrow" => [
            "limit" => [
                "_base" => 0,
                // orc
                "o" => 50,
                "o-p-d" => 50,
                "o-p-f" => 150,

                // elf
                "e" => 1000,
                "e-b-d" => 150,
                "e-b-f" => 1000,
                "e-p-d" => 50,
                "e-p-f" => 2000,
            ]
        ]
    ];

    /** This "map" is purely for example - you may end up using ids 
     *  or something more consistent.
     *  I would recommend using a different system, such as enums or constants.
     */
    public $serial_keys = [
        "orc"    => "o",
        "elf"    => "e",
        "basic"  => "b",
        "pro"    => "p",
        "desert" => "d",
        "forest" => "f",
    ];

    public function getSerializedLimit(Character $character, string $item_id) {
        $item = $this->serialized_items[$item_id];
        $item_limit = $item["limit"];

        $actual_limit = $item_limit["_base"];
        
        // serialize character
        // this could be done in various ways - this is purely for example

        // start with most specific
        $serial = $this->serial_keys[$character->race] . "-" . $this->serial_keys[$character->tier] . "-" . $this->serial_keys[$character->area];

        while ($serial !== "") {
            if (isset($item_limit[$serial])) {
                $actual_limit = $item_limit[$serial];
                break;
            }

            // remove most specific section
            // here we are expected each section to be a single character
            // be removing 2 characters, we remove the hyphen as well
            // NOTE: this hyphen is only here to help visualize
            //       you could very easily use 1 character without
            //       the hyphen and change this to `-1`
            $serial = substr($serial, -2);
        }

        return $actual_limit;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Adding example compiling nested array**

As mentioned in the comments, you won't have to manually adjust the array - instead you could have it compile on load/initialise of the market. The code below shows an example datasource setup and code to compile the nested array.

This can also easily be adjusted to re-created the serialized array.

```php
<?php
Datasource: `item`
| item_id | name  | limit |
|---------|-------|-------|
| arrow   | Arrow | 0     |

Datasource: race
| race_id | `name` |
|---------|--------|
| elf     | Elf    |
| orc     | Orc    |

Datasource: `tier`
| tier_id | name  |
|---------|-------|
| basic   | Basic |
| pro     | Pro   |

Datasource: `area`
| area_id | name   |
|---------|--------|
| forest  | Forest |
| desert  | Desert |

Datasource: `item_limit`
| item_id | race_id | tier_id | area_id | limit |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|-------|
| arrow   | orc     | NULL    | NULL    | 50    |
| arrow   | orc     | pro     | forest  | 150   |
| arrow   | elf     | NULL    | NULL    | 1000  |
| arrow   | elf     | basic   | desert  | 150   |
| arrow   | elf     | pro     | desert  | 50    |
| arrow   | elf     | pro     | forest  | 2000  |


// Using these - compile to nested array (i.e. you only need to maintain the datasources, not the array)

$items = ... // results from `item` datasource;
$races = ... // results from `race` datasource;
$tiers = ... // results from `tier` datasource;
$areas = ... // results from `area` datasource;

$nested_array = [];
foreach($items as $item){
    $limit_data = ["_base" => $item["limit"]];
    // populate races
    $limit_data["race"] = [];
    foreach($races as $race){
        $race_data = ["tier" => []];

        // populate tiers
        foreach($tiers as $tier){
            $tier_data = ["area" => []];

            foreach($areas as $area){
                $tier_data["area"][$area["area_id"]] = [];
            }

            $race_data["tier"][$tier["tier_id"]] = $tier_data;
        }

        $limit_data["race"][$race["race_id"]] = $race_data;
    }

    $item_limits = ... // results from `item_limit` datasource filtered by `item_id`
    foreach($item_limits as $item_limit){
        // expects "less specific" columns to always be set
        // i.e. if `area` is set, `tier` and `race` should be too

        // assigning variable by reference to keep this example short
        $parent =& $limit_data["race"][$item_limit["race_id"]];

        if(!isset($item_limit["tier_id"])){
            $parent["_base"] = $item_limit["limit"];
            continue;
        }

        $parent =& $parent["tier"][$item_limit["tier_id"]];

        if(!isset($item_limit["area_id"])){
            $parent["_base"] = $item_limit["limit"];
            continue;
        }

        $parent["area"][$item_limit["area_id"]] = $item_limit["limit"];
    }

    $nested_array[$item["item_id"]] = ["limit" => $limit_data];
}
```

**Memory Considerations**

The above code shows how you *could* implement a system like this. However, in a live environment with many items, it would be better to only initialise/compile the nested/serialized array for a specific item as needed. Caching is your friend here.

Alternatively you can take this same approach and implement it in such a way that it only needs to query the datasource to reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: This nested array is hardly maintainable. Just imagine how much editing it requires to add a new item or area. I used `Arrow` to simplify the example. `Arrow` is a child of `Item`. The market can have hundreds of items (currently 230). Additionally, there are 9 different areas.

Comment: @VirtualDevice you wouldn't store the nested array as shown in this example - this is essentially what it *could* compile down to. Ideally this array is built from a datasource that is easier to manage. The nested array also opens up the possibility of changing other attributes depending on the character (if necessary).

Comment: @VirtualDevice another approach could be to have an "overrides" set of data. This would have to reference specific conditions and would need a `priority` field to ensure overrides are applied in the correct order. Without the `priority` field, you would need to manually define the priority.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions actually.

1. How to build the character hierarchy with design pattern
2. How to rule the market with validation

This is my modeling suggestion
[image]

To the first problems. There are different properties to define a `Character`. `Race` and `Tier`. I am not sure if `Area` is the location of the character position. Or it is the biome of the character. If latter, then the character properties become three. I suggest to model the hierarchy with composition over inheritance. Otherwise, using traditional inheritance would result in many combination of classes (default Orc, Basic Orc, Pro Orc etc). Not to mention if more `Race` or `Tier` to come in the future.

To the second problem, I would not recommend chain of responsibility. Because with CoR, you need to define a long chain. Each processing object handle a variation of Character. You will need many processing object similar to the first problem.

I suggest to have a data structure registered what kind of Character could trade how many items. In my suggestion this is the responsibility of `MarketAuthority`. Imagine it has a map-like structure inside, and each entry it has a record call `MarketRegulation`. `MarketRegulation` define what kind of `Character` can buy or sell how many items. When trade happens, pass the character to `MarketAuthority` and find which `MarketRegulation` match the character. From the `MarketRegulation` result you know how many the character can trade.

Below is the example of `MarketAuthority` implementation.

```php
class MarketAuthority
{

    private $regulations;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->regulations = array();
        // setting up regulations. Ideally they should be come from data source
        // orc
        $orc = new Character(null, null, new Orc());
        array_push($this->regulations, new MarketRegulation($orc, new ActualLimit(50), TradeType::BUY));
        .
        .
        .

        // basic orc
        $basicOrc = new Character(new Basic(), null, new Orc());
        array_push($this->regulations, new MarketRegulation($basicOrc, new ActualLimit(50), TradeType::BUY));

        $proForestOrc = new Character(new Pro(), new Forest(), new Orc());
        array_push($this->regulations, new MarketRegulation($proForestOrc, new ActualLimit(150), TradeType::BUY));

        // more to be set ...

    }

    public function buyCheck(Character $character, int $quantity): bool
    {
        $regulation = $this->getRegulation($character, TradeType::BUY);
        return $regulation->getLimit()->allow($character, $quantity);
    }

    public function sellCheck(Character $character, int $quantity): bool
    {
        $regulation = $this->getRegulation($character, TradeType::SELL);
        return $regulation->getLimit()->allow($character, $quantity);
    }

    public function buy(Character $character, int $quantity)
    {
        if ($this->buyCheck($character, $quantity)) {
            $arrow = $character->getArrow() + $quantity;
            $character->setArrow($arrow);
        }
    }

    public function sell(Character $character, int $quantity)
    {
        if ($this->sellCheck($character, $quantity)) {
            $arrow = $character->getArrow();
            $character->setArrow($arrow - $quantity);
        }
    }

    public function getRegulation(Character $character, TradeType $tradeType): MarketRegulation
    {
        $regulation = array_filter($this->regulations, function (MarketRegulation $r) use ($character, $tradeType) {
            return $r->getCharacterConfig()->equals($character) && $r->getTradeType() == $tradeType;
        });

        return array_pop($regulation);
    }
}
```

For a runnable prototype, please visit https://github.com/stackoverflow-helpdesk/free-market. Below is the prototype console output, simulating how the `MarketAuthority` regulate trades.

```
Basic Desert Elf [0] can buy up to 150 arrow
Basic Desert Elf [0] buy arrow*150
Basic Desert Elf [150]
Basic Desert Elf [150] only sell up to 50%. i.e.75
Basic Desert Elf [150] sell arrow*80
Basic Desert Elf [150]
Basic Desert Elf [150] cannot sell arrow*80
Orc [0] can buy up to 50 arrow
Orc [0] buy arrow*80
Orc [0]
Orc [0] cannot buy arrow*80
```

Comment: I was also thinking of the Composite Pattern, but I need a lower layout to override the upper.  With Composite Pattern, I see that the upper layout limits would override limits of the lower layout

Comment: Codewise speaking, I am not sure I understand the concept and implementation of `MarketAuthority`.  Could you provide some code?

Comment: In my suggestion, it is not the character to control how many arrow he can buy, it is `MarketAuthority`’s duty. Therefore, the information of trade quota is not stored in character class, thus you do not need to consider property overriding.

Comment: Speaking `MarketAuthority` it is just a fancy name of a controller class. What it does it to manage the market, so a kind of character could only trade a number of arrow they are allowed. I am not proficiency in php, anyway let me try to make a demo. Stay turned.

Comment: @VirtualDevice updated the answer with runnable prototype on github